# Time-orderings for the time-like and light-like vectors cannot be altered

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, group-theory, causality, information

My question concerns the time-ordering for the time-like vector between two space-time points:
$$ (t_1,\vec{x_1}) \text{ and } (t_2,\vec{x_2})$$

Is it correct to claim that:

> 1. For a time-like vector, $(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2>0$, it is always impossible to do a Lorentz transformation, such that the time-ordering of two events, at $t_1$ and $t_2$, may switch their time-ordering?

Suppose $ (t_1,\vec{x_1}) \text{ and } (t_2,\vec{x_2})$ can be Lorentz transformed to
$ (t_1',\vec{x_1'}) \text{ and } (t_2',\vec{x_2'})$,
or $ (t_1'',\vec{x_1''}) \text{ and } (t_2'',\vec{x_2''})$.
Of course,
$$(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2=
(t_1'-t_2')^2-(\vec{x_1'}-\vec{x_2'})^2=
(t_1''-t_2'')^2-(\vec{x_1''}-\vec{x_2''})^2>0.$$

> 2. It is always impossible to find the case that:
>    $$
>    t_1-t_2>0, \quad t_1'-t_2'=0, \quad t_1''-t_2''<0?
>    $$

> 3. Are the above claims also true for a light-like vector, $(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2=0$? but it is false for the space-like vector, $(t_1-t_2)^2-(\vec{x_1}-\vec{x_2})^2<0$?

Answer (score 2):

If $(t_1 - t_2)^2 - (x_1 - x_2)^2 > 0$ and this quantity is preserved under Lorentz transform, then can $t_1 - t_2 = 0$? Try making them simultaneous, and you find that

$-(x_1 - x_2)^2 > 0$

which is impossible, since a square of a real quantity is always non-negative.

Then, changing the order will also be impossible, as you would need to pass through $t_1 = t_2$ to reach $t_1 > t_2$ from $t_1 < t_2$

Another way to say this, is that any event #2 which occurs in event #1's future light cone must occur after event #1.

Directly from the definition of the Lorentz transformation,

$ct' = \gamma (ct-x\beta)$

$ct_1' - ct_2' = \gamma(ct_1 - ct_2 - x_1\beta + x_2\beta)$ but $|\beta(x_1 - x_2)| < |ct_1 - ct_2|$ for a timelike interval (noting
$|\beta| < 1$) so the sign of $(ct_1' - ct_2')$ will not change for any $\beta$.

Comment: thanks - I voted - there are two more related questions I posted